# Implicit function theorem => continuously differentiable functions

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider the curve in $R^3$ consisting of the intersection of the paraboloid $z=x^2 + y^2$ and the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. Near which points of this curve does the implicit function theorem say we can write the curves as the graph of continuously differentiable functions $y = y(x), z=z(x)$?

Comment: Probably near all the points, since the intersection is simply a circle moved up one unit in the z direction.

Comment: Hold on: probably not near $(1,0,1),(-1,0,1)$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the intersection is just $x^2+y^2=1$.  So, $z$ is the constant function $1$.  Second, $y$ is a function of $x$ precisely where $\frac{dy}{dx}$ exists.  Using implicit differentiation, we land at
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y}.
$$
So, $y$ is a function of $x$ for $y\neq 0$.

The way to think about this is to draw the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ and observe around which points on the curve have an area around them that passes the vertical line test.

Comment: Just a nitpick: the intersection is the circle $x^2+y^2=1$ lying in the plane $z=1$, not the entire cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ (as a subset of 3-space). Otherwise this answer is on the mark. +1.